# How to connect the output of one network to the input of another network in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have two networks with given architectures:

```
hidden_state = 256
embedding_size = 128

# Encoder
enc_input = Input(shape=(max_fr_len,), name='enc_input')
x = Embedding(en_vocab, embedding_size)(enc_input)
x = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)(x)
enc_output = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=False)(x)


# Decoder
dec_input_seq = Input(shape=(max_en_len), name='dec_input_seq')
dec_hidden_state = Input(shape=(hidden_state,), name='dec_hidden_state')

x = Embedding(en_vocab, embedding_size)(dec_input_seq)
x = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)(x, initial_state=dec_hidden_state)
x = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)(x, initial_state=dec_hidden_state)
x = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)(x, initial_state=dec_hidden_state)
dec_output = Dense(en_vocab, activation='softmax')(x)
```

I would like to create another network that share parameters with two others with name `model` in such way that the `dec_hidden_state` is connected to `enc_output` so hidden state is passed to `GRU` units. 
Just to be clear I want to create model that as its inputs has `enc_input` and `dec_input_seq` (since `dec_hidden_state` is already connected) and outputs `dec_output`.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes, delightful help as always, thank you. Anyways for anyone wondering I found a solution. It is not my idea, however I decided to post it.

Instead of connecting it on fly you need to only instantiate layers and create two separate functions to connect it later on. Full code below.

```
# Encoder

enc_input = Input(shape=(None,), name='enc_input')
enc_embedding = Embedding(fr_vocab, embedding_size)
enc_gru1 = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)
enc_gru2 = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)
enc_gru3 = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=False)


# Decoder
dec_input_seq = Input(shape=(None,), name='dec_input_seq')
dec_hidden_state = Input(shape=(hidden_state,), name='dec_hidden_state')

dec_embedding = Embedding(en_vocab, embedding_size)
dec_gru1 = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)
dec_gru2 = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)
dec_gru3 = GRU(hidden_state, return_sequences=True)
dec_dense = Dense(en_vocab, activation='softmax', name='decoder_output')

def connect_encoder():
    x = enc_input
    x = enc_embedding(x)
    x = enc_gru1(x)
    x = enc_gru2(x)
    x = enc_gru3(x)
    return x

def connect_decoder(hidden_state):
    x = dec_input_seq
    x = dec_embedding(x)
    x = dec_gru1(x, initial_state=hidden_state)
    x = dec_gru2(x, initial_state=hidden_state) 
    x = dec_gru3(x, initial_state=hidden_state)
    x = dec_dense(x)
    return x

encoder_output = connect_encoder()
decoder_output = connect_decoder(dec_hidden_state)

encoder = Model(inputs=enc_input, outputs=encoder_output)
decoder = Model(inputs=[dec_input_seq, dec_hidden_state], outputs=decoder_output)

decoder_output = connect_decoder(encoder_output)
model = Model(inputs=[enc_input, dec_input_seq], outputs=decoder_output)
```